# Как в BeautifulSoup 4 вывести не первое совпадение, а второе?

Tags: python, python-3.x, парсер, beautiful-soup, bs4

Есть html в котором по указанному ниже контейнеру есть нужная мне информация, но дело в том что контейнеров с одинаковым классом в коде четыре, а мне нужен второй.

Если делать через find_all получается слишком много мусора.

```
soup = soup.find('div', class_="catalog-filter-list-wrap")
```

Answer (score 0):

Сделал поиск через css-селектор с использованием `:nth-of-type(2)`:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

root = BeautifulSoup("""
<div class="catalog-filter-list-wrap">1</div>
<div class="catalog-filter-list-wrap">2</div>
<div class="catalog-filter-list-wrap">3</div>
""", 'html.parser')

item = root.select_one('div.catalog-filter-list-wrap:nth-of-type(2)')
print(item)
# <div class="catalog-filter-list-wrap">2</div>
```

Еще можно через `find_all` с обращение к второму элементу из результата:

```
item = root.find_all('div', class_='catalog-filter-list-wrap')[1]
print(item)
# <div class="catalog-filter-list-wrap">2</div>
```